# Oracle, Select Distinct columns, with corresponding columns

Tags: oracle

I want to select **DISTINCT** results from the **user_id** column but I need the corresponding columns as well.

Result set needs to return two role_id that are **Distnct** **user_id** and be not an '**Unassigned**' status.

The query I am using:

```
SELECT role_id, user_id, role_code, status_code FROM table where school_id=5 and status_code= 'DRAFT';
```

This an example of my table:

```
ROLE_ID USER_ID SCHOOL_ID CAMPUS_ID ROLE_CODE STATUS_CODE 
   1       4        5         7      Unassigned   DRAFT
   2       4        5         7        TEST       DRAFT
   3       4        5         8        TEST       DRAFT
   4       5        5         9      Unassigned  DRAFT
   5       5        5         9        TEST       DRAFT
   6       5        5         10       TEST       DRAFT
```

I have tried to add group by based on user_id but I get an ORA-00979.

Comment: Please provide the expected result. It's not clear to me [anymore] what exactly do you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the rows you want. For example:

```
select *
from (
  select t.*,
    row_number() over(partition by user_id order by role_id) as rn
  from t
  where role_code <> 'Unassigned'
) x
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` is across the entire set of columns and not for one specific column. Therefore, if you want to get the `DISTINCT` rows which are not `Unassigned` you can use:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       role_id,
       user_id,
       role_code,
       status_code
FROM   table
where  school_id   = 5
and    status_code = 'DRAFT'
and    role_code   != 'Unassigned';
```

If you want to get a single row for each `user_id` then you can use `GROUP BY` and find the minimum `role_id`:

```sql
SELECT MIN(role_id) AS role_id,
       user_id,
       MIN(role_code  ) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY role_id) AS role_code,
       MIN(status_code) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY role_id) AS status_code
FROM   table
where  school_id   = 5
and    status_code = 'DRAFT'
and    role_code   != 'Unassigned'
GROUP BY
       user_id;
```